# How do I loop through all of my Git repositories and update them?

Tags: git, bash

I have a folder where I keep all of my Git repos. I usually just do `git pull` to get my changes, but now that I have over 50 repos it becomes a burden to have to do this for every folder.

How can I run a command that will loop through every repo and update it for me?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Bash you can run this command which will loop through every repo in your working directory, stash your changes, fetch the origin and pull the latest commit.

```
for d in */; do cd $d; git stash; (git pull &); cd ..; done
```

Some things to note:

- This will use your working branch in your repo
- `(git pull &)` opens a subshell and executes in the background

Comment: According to `man git-pull`: _In its default mode, `git pull` is shorthand for `git fetch` followed by `git merge FETCH_HEAD`_.

Comment: You might consider checking whether `.git` is a directory, so you don't waste time on directories that don't happen to be git repos.